# Term for making a synonym?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

When you give the definition of a word, you define it, but what(if there is) is the word for giving a synonym of a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is to [synonymize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synonymize) , but it is not a common expression. You can say *to provide a synonym/synonyms*:

> - To analyze or provide the synonyms of (a word or taxon).

(American Heritage® Dictionary)

> - (Linguistics) (tr) to analyse the synonyms of or provide with synonyms.

(Collins)

Comment: Synonymize was the very first word that came to my mind when reading the question, but it seemed too obvious to be true. Well I'll be damned... ;)